# Adding a card flip animation to this JS card game?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I am playing around with [this card game](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/jsexamples/solitaire.html#demonstration) and I want to add a card flip animation.

I have googled for an answer, but most solutions refer to jquery (which I don't want to implement just for 1 animation) or CSS3 ([I liked this example](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip)). Not much luck there.

The js game uses the following (from cardgamecore.js):

`playingCard.redrawCardImage()` Forces a card to redraw

`playingCard.showFace(bool: face)` Sets the card to be either face up or face down, and redraws if needed. true = face up, false = face down.

```
playingCard.prototype.redrawCardImage = function () {
    // Set or change the image showing on the card face
    if( !this.faceImage || !this.cardSet.backImage ) { return; }
    // Bug in Firefox - alt attributes do not change unless they are made _before_ an SRC change
    this.cardImage.setAttribute('alt',this.wayup?(this.cardSet.cardNames[this.number-1]+' '+this.suit):this.cardSet.cardWord);
    this.cardImage.src = this.wayup ? this.faceImage : this.cardSet.backImage;
};

playingCard.prototype.showFace = function (oWhich) {
    // Used to flip a card over
    if( this.redrawNewImage != oWhich ) {
        this.wayup = oWhich;
        this.redrawCardImage();
    }
};
```

So when a card shows its back then `playingCard.showFace = false`. When you click on it, `playingCard.showFace = true`and the image is redrawn. At this point the card should have a nice flip animation.

But how to do this?

Comment: What problems are you facing with the CSS3 example that you liked?

Comment: Well it's more like where to add the code to make it work. Is something like `addClass X` (where X has the css3 flip animation) sufficient? And if it is that simple, do I put this in the `showFace` or `redrawCardImage`function?

Comment: It is as simple as adding a class, I think it would be better in showFace. Im not sure if redrawCardImage is needed anymore though because you can just have both the front and back image in the css and not show the back of the card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted the author of the script and he told me it is not possible in the current script without re-writing most of the code. So this question can be closed. All thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to google search is "css 3 flip animation"

http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a card game as well...

First you could write you card like this:

```
<div class='card' >
   <div class='faces'>
       <div class='face front'> Hello</div>
       <div class='face back'>Goodbye</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Both faces are accounted for in your html the css will only display one though:

```
.card {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
   width: 50%;
   height: 300px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 3px;
   float:left; /*if you want more than one card in a line*/

}
.card .faces.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg); /* this style will help the card to rotate */
}
.card .faces {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; /* This is a 3d transformation */
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;/*the animation last 0.5secs*/
}
.card .faces .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ; /*hides the back of the card until transform*/
  z-index: 2;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
.card .faces .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.card .faces .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg); /*allows the flip to the back of the card*/
  background-image: url("image.jpg"); /*background image for the back if you want*/
  background-size:100%;
  color:white;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

The only thing left to do is add the 'flipped' class. So maybe instead of redrawing.

```
   $(".card").on('click',function(){
      $(this).children('.faces').toggleClass('flipped');
  });
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w2q2E/1/)